# Blocking a pull-down menu in Android

Tags: android

We have an industrial app running on stock Samsung Android devices.   Because it's an industrial app we are trying to have it "take over" the device.   We've got this pretty well working by setting in the manifest

```
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

and by intercepting the Android "back" key via onBackPressed and doing nothing.

Our one remaining conundrum is that Samsung's UI layer, 'Touch Wiz', has a pull-down menu that the user can pull down over the top of our app and access other features from.    We're trying to disable that.

Is there anything we can intercept that the way we did the the back button to block that?  Any other way to block it?

(if someone suggests "rooting" the device, what could I do as root that would help here?)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which stock samsung device are you working with?

and by pull down menu are you speaking of the Notification Bar?

[image: Notification Bar]

If so this is not a UI feature that is specific to TouchWiz, they may have modified what all can be accessed from the expanded notification bar. But this element exists in stock android as well.

If this is what you are referring to you can set a full_screen flag on your activity or application elements in your manifest. This will hide the notification bar while inside your application.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: It works!! I thank you, my boss thanks you, etc.    I wasn't sure whether it was a regular notification bar or not because it shows different things from my personal HTC Droid Incredible, but it did the trick! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work with fullscreen mode home app:

A stock Android has no way to do real kiosk mode and I guess it's not a goal of Android to allow this since you could do evil things with that like build apps that force you to pay money before you can leave them again.

Root will not help here too since that's about the underlying Linux which allows you to access internal files etc. That does not unlock some magically hidden APIs.

What you would need to do is build your own firmware for the device (there might exist something for the device - look in http://forum.xda-developers.com/). In that firmware you are free to change those internals that allow users to escape your app.